# Ambiguous call to overloaded function (learning about templates)

Tags: c++

I started learning about templates and I copied the code from my book but the compiler is giving me this error

> Error 1 error: 'swap' : ambiguous call to overloaded function"

Here is my program

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X>
void swap(X &a, X &b);

int _tmain(){
    using namespace std;
    int a, b;

    cout << "enter two numbers:\n";
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "Your numbers are: " << a << ", " << b << endl;

    swap(a, b); //error is here
    cout << "Your numbers reversed are: " << a << ", " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}

template <typename X>
void swap(X &a, X &b){
    X temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: remove `using namespace std;`. A `std::swap` exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redefining the function swap with the same signature, so you're having an ambiguous definition of it, and, consequently, an ambiguous call.

If you want to maintain the function with the same signature, you should either choose to use not the "using namespace std;", which will not shadow your swap() definition, or simply define tthe function in another namespace.

Example:

```
namespace your_namespace {

    template <typename X>
    void swap(X &a, X &b) {
        X temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

}

int foo(10), bar(20);
std::cout << "foo: " << foo << "; bar: " << bar << std::endl;

your_namespace::swap(foo, bar);
std::cout << "foo: " << foo << "; bar: " << bar << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
foo: 10; bar: 20
foo: 20; bar: 10
```

Regards!

Comment: This is how my book does it, how else would I define the function without using the same signature as in the prototype?

Comment: Well, for this specific case, if you really need to have the same name to the function, you should define your function in another namespace, or simply not use "using namespace std", in order to be able to use the space of names of your own program. Any other than this, you could simply add an underscore by the beginning or end of the name, or change the number of parameters.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I didn't understand from the first explanation that swap() was actually a function in the std namespace... I had the same code as the author except his was Swap with a capital S and he didn't explain the reason for it so I thought it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You're very welcome! In smaller activities or simple tests, applying "using namespace std;" is very handy, but in bigger applications or projects, it's good to relate to the namespace you're using, like "std::swap(a, b);" or "std::cout << ... << std::endl;", so that other people will be able to know where the function you're using came from.